# Null value received in Insomnia while sending Post Request with mongoose, how to fix?

Tags: mongoose

Im using insomnia and im trying to have it send me back the username that I added in compass.However when I do it comes back as null.

I've been racking my brain but no dice.

**This is my index.js**

```
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import morgan from "morgan";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path"
import { userRouter } from "./controllers/auth.js";

/* CONFIGURATIONS */

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config({ debug: true });

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(cors());

/* ROUTES */

app.use("/auth", userRouter)


 /* MONGOOSE SETUP */

 const PORT = process.env.PORT;
 mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
 }).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT,() => console.log(`Server Started! On Port: ${PORT}`))
}).catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`))
```

**
My auth.js**

```
import express from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import UserModel from "../models/user.js"

const router = express.Router();

/* REGISTER USER */

router.post("/register", async(req,res) => {

    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username:username });
    res.json(user)
});


export { router as userRouter };
```

**My model/schema **

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)
export default UserModel
```

[This is the respose in insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVkse.png)
[This is the info I added in compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjnUk.png)

I dont know if my error is in the "export { router as userRouter }" or "app.use("/auth", userRouter)"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, the issue may lie in the way you're handling the database connection and the environment variables.

First, make sure you have set up the .env file correctly and that the MONGO_URL variable is properly configured. Ensure that the MongoDB server is running and accessible.

Next, ensure that you've imported the required packages and set up the necessary middleware properly in your index.js file. Here's an updated version of the code that incorporates the changes:

```js
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import morgan from "morgan";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path";
import { userRouter } from "./controllers/auth.js";

dotenv.config({ debug: true });

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/auth", userRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started! On Port: ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

Make sure you have the necessary packages installed (dotenv, cors, mongoose, express, body-parser, morgan) by running npm install or yarn install.

Double-check the .env file to ensure it contains the correct values, particularly the MONGO_URL.

With these changes, your server should be able to connect to the MongoDB database and handle requests properly.